# What is wrong with the dependence of result with the order of the operation in my computation of Higgs sector derivative term?

Tags: operators, standard-model, higgs

In Standard Model Higgs sector, there are terms that introduce :

$\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{\mu}+i\frac{g}{2}W_{\mu}^3+i\frac{g'}{2}B_{\mu} &i\frac{g}{2}W_{\mu}^1+\frac{g}{2}W_{\mu}^2\\
i\frac{g}{2}W_{\mu}^1-\frac{g}{2}W_{\mu}^2   &\partial_{\mu}-i\frac{g}{2}W_{\mu}^3+i\frac{g'}{2}B_{\mu}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\phi^{+}\\
\phi^{0}
\end{array}
\right)$

If we restrict only to contributions with partial derivatives : this gives

$\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{\mu} &0\\
0  &\partial_{\mu}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\phi^{+}\\
\phi^{0}
\end{array}
\right)
$

When computing the term $\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger}$, it seems that the result depends whether we first do the multiplication and then transpose/conjugate, or if we first transpose/conjugate and then do the multiplication.

Here is my basic computation (restricting only to derivative terms):

- First approach

$\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{\mu}\phi^{+}\\
\partial_{\mu}\phi^{0}
\end{array}
\right)$

- Second approach

$\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger}=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\phi^{+} &\phi^{0}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\partial_{\mu} &0\\
0  &\partial_{\mu}
\end{array}
\right)
$

$\left(D_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger}=
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
\phi^{+}\partial_{\mu}\\
\phi^{0}\partial_{\mu}
\end{array}
\right)$

(which is different to result of first approach)

What is wrong with the dependence of result with the order of the operation in my computation of Higgs sector derivative term ?

So how could we obtain terms of the form $\partial_{\mu}\phi^+\partial^{\mu}\phi^+$ with the second approach ?

It seems that second approach would give : $\phi^+\partial_{\mu}\partial^{\mu}\phi^+$

Comment: You should not pass the derivative through the field when computing the adjoint -- it itself is not a field and, in fact, when working with lagrangians we are almost always dealing with things at a classical level so that it is not even operator-valued. In any case $(\partial_\mu \phi)^\dagger=\partial_\mu \phi^\dagger$.

Comment: @GaloisFan : sorry : what is meaning "pass the derivative through the field" ? And what is your first "it" ? Is "it" the "derivative" or the "adjoint" ? And what is your second "it" ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian both occurances of it refer to the derivative.

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian You implied $(\partial_\mu \phi)^\dagger=\phi \partial_\mu$: this is nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is straightforward notation. Recall the rules for transposing product orders in the adjoint.

- First approach
  $$\left(\partial_{\mu}\Phi\right)=
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \partial_{\mu}\phi^{+}\\
  \partial_{\mu}\phi^{0}
  \end{array}
  \right)~~~~\Longrightarrow \\
  \left(\partial_{\mu}\Phi\right)^\dagger=
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \partial_{\mu}\phi^{+}\\
  \partial_{\mu}\phi^{0}
  \end{array}
  \right)^\dagger= (\partial_{\mu}\phi^{-}, \partial_{\mu}\phi^{0~*}).
  $$
- Second approach
  $$\left(\partial_{\mu}\Phi\right)^{\dagger}
  = \Phi^{\dagger}  \partial_{\mu}^\dagger= \Phi^{\dagger} \overset{_\gets}\partial_\mu= 
  \left(
  \begin{array}{cc}
  \partial_{\mu}\phi^{+}\\
  \partial_{\mu}\phi^{0}
  \end{array}
  \right)^\dagger  ,
  $$
  which is just the first approach.

You thus have
$$
\left(\partial_{\mu}\Phi\right)^\dagger\partial^{\mu}\Phi =\partial_{\mu}\phi^{-} \partial^{\mu}\phi^{+} + \partial_{\mu}\phi^{0~*}\partial^{\mu}\phi^{0}.  $$

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, is the explanation of @GaloisFan wrong ? ("You should not pass the derivative through the field when computing the adjoint")

Comment: I am not sure I understand it, but he *is* right that (∂)†=∂†,  as you saw in the second approach.